# File permission issues

Tags: permissions, directory

Is it possible to change the permissions of a particular directory containing some files from 640, with which it gets generated in that folder and change it to 644 once the files are generated for some specific users to access those files?

Environment - RHEL 6 running an Oracle database

Comment: `ownership` is something and `permission` is something totally different. `640` is permission and not ownership so your question does not make sense, can you please make it clearer ?

Comment: permissions is what I mean.

Comment: ... then [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/253661/edit) is what you should do ...

Comment: If your filesystem supports [ACLs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl), you can give files that are created in a directory special permissions "on birth", but that doesn't handle the "once they are generated" (i.e., finished) workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `chmod(1)` man page.

`640` stands for `rw-r-----` which is: owner can read/write (first triplet), users in the group that owns the file (second triplet) can read, anybody else may not do anything.

To change it to `644` (all can read, owning user can write) you either add read permissions for others:

```
$ chmod o+w file
```

or set explicitly via:

```
$ chmod 644 file
```

or

```
$ chmod a=r,u+w
```

That said, make sure whether you are changing permissions for a directory or a file (it is not that clear from your question). The important thing here is that removing the executable permission from a directory makes it untraversable - that is those who do not have executable rights for a directory can't change into it (nor read the files inside of it).

Answer (score 1):

ACLs is exactly what you are looking for in this situation and they are supported in RHEL 6. So, for example, you have these files being put into a specific directory: /dir

You want to maintain the permissions that directory currently has but you also want to give a specific group or user access to that dir and its descendants who can not access that folder or its contents. For example, if you want to give a group read access, then you would run the following command:

`setfacl -dR -m "g:groupname:rwX" /dir`

The `-d` sets the acl as default so that when anything new is added into this directory, it will inherit the acl of `/dir`.

The `-R` is for recursive.

The big `X` ensures that users in that group can `cd` into the directories, it does not make the files inside executable.

Then you can run the following to make sure it was applied properly:

`getfacl /dir`

Here is the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) for `setfacl`:

Comment: I want the files generated inside that folder to have the 'execute' permissions and not just read.. what should be the changes? say I have a folder named abc with ownership user1 and files generated inside that abc has permissions 640 and I want it to be 644. How is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 0):

How does the system know that the file(s) has/have been completely created?

If some process creates the file(s) and you have any control over that process, then I'd suggest adding a step at the end to change the permissions of the files.

If, instead, you have no control over the process by which the files are created, then your best option is probably to run a cron job every few minutes.  That job should look for files that haven't been changed for a while (to make sure you don't find ones that are still being written) with the permissions you want to change, and should change the permissions.  Something like:

```
find /the/directory -type f -mmin +5 -perm 0640 -exec chmod 644 '{}' ';'
```

Run that every five minutes from cron and you should have a relatively robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is change the permissions which are assigned by default to a file when it is created.

If so, I think you need to check out `help umask`.

The `umask` setting is what determines what permissions are assigned to a file (or a directory) when it is created.  (There are other factors involved as well; I'm not trying to give a tutorial here, just a definition and a starting point.  If you know the search term to use your research can be much faster.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the permission, you can use the chmod  command. If.  Chmod 777 filename with give read,write,exercise permission to user,groups and everyone else on the os